# FakeItEasy How to raise event, type delegate

Tags: events, delegates, fakeiteasy, raise, unit-testing

```
namespace Elektrobit.Guide.Studio.Model.Elements
{
    public delegate void ModifiedChangedHandler();

    public interface IProject : IModelElement
    {
        event ModifiedChangedHandler ModifieChanged;
    }
}
```

I need to raise this event using FakeItEasy.

Comment: The solution: Refactoring the code, using EventHandler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update: supported as of FakeItEasy 2.0.0. See [Raising Events](http://fakeiteasy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/raising-events/) for more information, but the gist is that you would use `fake.ModifieChanged += Raise.With<ModifiedChangedHandler >()`**

Unfortunately, this is not currently supported. [Issue 30](https://github.com/FakeItEasy/FakeItEasy/issues/30) has been raised about this and I have a proposed fix awaiting review.

In the meantime, if you cannot or prefer not to refactor to use an ‘EventHandler‘ style of event, you can capture the event registration manually and then call the handler yourself.